# Modifying Crystal Reports v1.0.38 Forms

Tags: visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports

You read that correctly, CR v1.0.38.  We have an archaic piece of coldfusion software that uses reports created in CR v1.0.38.  Some of these reports need minor adjustments, so I open it using Visual Studio make the adjustments.  When I go to save it I'm prompted with a warning about only being able to save it as a newer version.  When I attempt to pull the report using the saved .rpt file it locks up.

Do any of you CR gurus know how I could edit and save a CR report into CR v1.0.38 format?  The only Crystal Reports editing software I currently have is Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a text editor such as TextPad or NotePad++ to try and edit the .rpt file. It's possible that such an early version of Crystal will have a fairly simplistic model that may be succesfully modified "in the raw." Especially if the changes you need to make are indeed simple. I don't expect any Crystal editor written since '95 to be able to read a 1.* rpt file.

I have actually done something similar in version 5 of Crystal to address a persistence bug. (Crystal 5 threw in an extra squiggly brace on save sometimes into rpt file... )

**EDIT:** Found a [page of links](http://www.kenhamady.com/bookmarks.html) to Crystal Utils that may help you. Perhaps better options than text editing the raw rpt!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, old enough that it was actually called Quik Reports. Oldest thing I know for editing Crystal Reports would be the version that comes with VB5 (or VB6 - same version) which was version 4.6 - there's a chance this might be old enough. If you can get an even older version, apparently Crystal has been bundled with VB since 1993, which would mean VB3.